# Transfer data from child component to parent component

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

I have a form (parent) component with two input text fields and date field for which vuejs-datepicker component is used (child component. See below:

Form component

```
<template>
<div>
    <form>
        Name<input type="text" v-model="name"/><br>
        Age <input type="text" v-model="age"/><br>
        <calendar2 @wybrano="zm($event)"></calendar2>
        <button type="button" @click="sendfo()">Wyslij</button>
    </form>
</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {

    data() {
        return {
            name:"",
            age:"",  
            da:""
        }
    },
    created() {


    },
    methods: {
        zm: function(ev) {
            this.da=ev
        },

        sendfo: function() {
            var t = this
            axios({
                method:"POST",
                url: "sendfo",
                data: {
                    name:"messi",
                    age:32,
                    data:t.da

                },
            }).then(function(response) {
                console.log('done');
            })



        }

    }
}
</script>
```

Calendar component

```
<template>
<div>
<datepicker v-model="data" name="data" :format="ff" :monday- 
first="mondayFirst" :clear-button="clearButton" :calendar- 
button="calendarButton" @selected="sel"></datepicker>
</div>
</template>

<script>
import Datepicker from 'vuejs-datepicker';
 export default {
components: {
  Datepicker
},
created() {


},


data() {
  return {
    data: "",
    mondayFirst: true,
    clearButton: true,
    calendarButton: true,
  }
},
methods: {
  sel: function() {
    if(this.data){
    this.data=this.data.toISOString().substr(0,10)
    this.$emit('wybrano', this.data)
    }
    },


    }
  }
</script>
```

My purpose is to use form component to collect form data and send them via ajax to database. As you can see in the code I use `$emit` to transfer data from calendar component to the parent component. Everything work almost fine but...  Selected (by user) date in calendar component is different than this date transferred to the parent component. I give few examples;

```
date selected in calendar 07/08/2018 -> var data="07/08/2018" -> var da=""
date selected in calendar 09/12/2018 -> var data="09/12/2018" -> var da="07/08/2018"
date selected in calendar 01/01/2018 -> var data="01/01/2018" -> var da="09/12/2018"
```

I hope my problem is understandable. Every time var `da` in parent component takes value from previous selection. Please help me solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

First thing I would try is change these two lines so you don't change the bound model value:

```
var payload=this.data.toISOString().substr(0,10)
this.$emit('wybrano', payload)
```

Comment: I changed but the problem still exists. Problem disappears when I replace 'methods' to 'computed'. After that there is another problem. I get a warning in the console 'Invalid handler for event "selected": got undefined'.I think it is because events can be served only by methods. Please help

Answer (score 0):

This issue is due to the fact that the *selected* event is propagated before the *data* property gets updated (thus causing the previous selected value to be emitted).

To be sure to propagate the selected date once it is updated, you could instead use a [watcher](https://it.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Watchers) method to observe changes for the data property.

Then, in the watcher method, you would emit your event as already done.

So in the *///Calendar* component you would have something like this, where @selected is removed:

```
<datepicker v-model="data" name="data" :format="ff" :monday- 
  first="mondayFirst" :clear-button="clearButton" :calendar- 
  button="calendarButton"></datepicker>
///
 methods: {
   ...
   watch: {
     'data' () {
       this.$emit('wybrano', this.data.toISOString().substr(0,10))
     }
   }
```

Then, I would advice you to use meaningful functions, variable names, in order to ease code readability and maintenance.

For example, you could rename *Calendar* *data* to *someDate* (some needs to be clarified). *wybrano* event named would be renamed to *someDateUpdated. *zm* function name also is not clear.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using `v-model` on the calendar component.

With this approach VueJS will may have the good reactivity to the selection of the date.

Documentation: [Using v-model on Components](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Using-v-model-on-Components)

/// Form component

```
...
<calendar2 v-model="da" />
...
```

/// Calendar component

```
... in the template
<datepicker v-model="value" input="$emit('input', $event.target.value.toISOString().substr(0,10))" ... />
...

... in the script
data() { /* datepicker configuration */ },
props: ['value'],
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it will be enough to change this line:

```
this.$emit('wybrano', this.data)
```

like this:

```
this.$nextTick(this.$emit('wybrano', this.data))
```

Comment: It would work too I guess, but, IMO, it would also make this code more complex and less understandable. $nextTick here, looks like a Hack

Comment: Not really. OP's question / problem is not about his codebase readability. He is not asking us to help him to make his code more readable. It's up to him to learn how to code in more declarative way. So, my answer is as simple as possible and pointing to core of his problem: when you change the DOM directly, then you should know about nextTick method and use it.